# Prevent unix find descending into unmatched directories

Tags: shell, find

This is a little complex, but I want to use the find command to search for items (files, directories etc.) and run a command to determine if they are to be included or not via the -exec parameter, however, I need to prevent find from descending into directories that have been excluded.

For example:

```
find . -exec sh -c 'echo "{}" | grep -i ".*/[a][^/]*"' \;
```

Bit of a weird example, but basically the above should only match items that begin with the letter a, however if you run it then even though it doesn't match directories that begin with other letters, find will still descend into them and return results if that directory contains items beginning with a letter a. For example, it will match the following:

```
./aFolder/aFile
./Foo/Bar/aFile
./aFolder/Foo/Bar/aFile
```

What I would like to do is prevent this from happening so that if a directory isn't matched then its contents are ignored as well, in the last example, ./aFolder would be matched, but when ./Foo is encountered the search should not continue into it.

Is there a way to prevent find from descending deeper if a directory is excluded, or a similar command than can be restricted in that way? Currently I'm using a custom shell script to do the recursion myself but it's not the most efficient way to do it for huge directory trees.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
find . \( -name . -or -exec sh -c 'echo "{}" | grep -iq "^.*/[a][^/]*\$"' \; -or \( -prune -false \) \) -print
```

A few changes from yours

- Add -q to the grep and -print to the find to make sure the output is what matched the find
- Add ^ and $ to the regex to make sure the whole file name is checked
- Add the -or ( -prune -false ) to ensure that non-matching items are not descended into or matched (-prune alone is a true)
- Finally, add the -name . otherwise the top level directory will fail and so, correctly, nothing would be returned

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that that's working as expected as it still seems to descend into directories. Here's the exact command I'm running: `find . \( -exec sh -c '[ $(stat -qf "%i" "'"$PREVIOUS"'/{}") != $(stat -qf "%i" "'"$TARGET"'/{}") ]; exit $?' \; -or \( -prune -false \) \) -print`. Basically it is checking if the inode of the current file differs from one in a previous directory, but it still descends.